# How run the power shell script after deploying to AKS using devops pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I can able to deploy to the Kubernetes POD and do the health check through the bash script.

But, after deploying to the Kubernetes windows notes.  All the files are available under the
`"wwwroot" folder.`

in that folder, wwwroot\DeployConfigs\ i have a batch file that will perform some copies of files to root folder based on the arguments applied.

```
copy_pay_configs.bat **dev\east**
```

When i run the power script, i am facing the below error.

```
line 2: cd: C:inetpubwwwrootDeployConfigs: No such file or directory

and 

line 3: copy_pay_configs.bat: command not found
```

could you please let me know if its possible login to the pod and run the batch file as we do in azure web service. I know through the kubectl login command i can able to login but unable to run the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried to do the same thing in my environment and got the below results.**

Method 1: Execute the Batch script in the Kubernetes pod from azure devops as below.
[image]

```
 - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'svc-01'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        az aks get-credentials --resource-group rgtest-01 --name myAKSClustertest01
        kubectl exec -it sample-877cb5f44-56f45 -- "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\file01.bat"
```

You can also refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-v0?view=azure-pipelines) to use **kubectl task** in Azure DevOps.

Method 2:
Execute the batch script in the Kubernetes pod from the azure cli as shown below.
[image]

Step 1: `az aks get-credentials --resource-group [resource-group-name] --name [AKSSClustername]`

Step 2: `kubectl exec -it sample-877cb5f44-56f45 -- "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\file01.bat"`

Comment: How to run the bat file with the arguments 
kubectl exec -it test-696cb5478b-xgnng -- "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DeployConfigs\copy_pay_configs.bat qa\westus"

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DeployConfigs\copy_pay_configs.bat - bat file
qa\westus - argument

Comment: kubectl exec -it test-696cb5478b-xgnng -- "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DeployConfigs\copy_pay_configs.bat" qa\westus  try this

Comment: its not working as well as not throwing error

Comment: ok let me check and come back to u on this, not how much I can help more, but again will give it a shot.

Comment: actually requirement u can get from the link, I have raised another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75482930/how-to-copy-or-moves-files-from-one-directory-to-another-directory-inside-the-ku